# Get column names from a mySql query even when no results are found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, backend

I'm using laravel to execute dynamic query strings sent by the front-end.

This is a dev environment used to speed up a development process.

Since I don't know what the queries will look like, I can't really use laravel query builder.

So this

```
$users = DB::table('look_up_lists')
    ->leftJoin('look_up_list_values', 'look_up_lists.id', '=', 'look_up_list_values.look_up_list_id')
    ->where('look_up_list_values.id', '=', 99)
    ->get();
```

WIll actually look like this

```
select * from `look_up_lists` left join `look_up_list_values` on `look_up_lists`.`id` = `look_up_list_values`.`look_up_list_id` where `look_up_list_values`.`id` = 99
```

In PHPmyAdmin, even when no results are thrown, you can see the columns involved.

[image: PHP my admin query result example]

This is exactly what I need, and I can't figure out a way to do this.
I managed to get the columns involved as long as there are results, but not when I don't have any.

I tried this:

```
 $sth =  DB::getPdo()->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute();
    return  $sth->fetchALl(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

again, works as long as there are results.

I'm stuck for days with this, can anyone help?

Comment: How are these queries being created? Are the tables involved known or can they be derived from the query?

Answer (score 0):

In case the result set is empty, I added a  *count(*) as ignore*  this will force an output of just one line and give you the column names,
or you dump the empty result in a temp table then you can use the simple select on teh tmep table.
Good luck.

```
      <?php
            include_once "../include/connect.pdo.php";
            
            $q = "select * from ttt";
            $xx = $connect_pdo->prepare($q);
            $xx->execute([]);
            $rows = $xx->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $n = count($rows);
            
            echo var_dump($rows);
            
           $q = "select *,count(*) as ingnor from ttt";
           $xx = $connect_pdo->prepare($q);
           $xx->execute([]);
           $rows = $xx->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
           $n = count($rows);
           echo "<p>". var_dump($rows);


// dump unknown query in temp-table then use the simple select with count

        $q = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1temp as (select * from ttt)";
        $xx = $connect_pdo->prepare($q);
        $xx->execute([]);
        $q = "select *,count(*) from t1temp";
        $xx = $connect_pdo->prepare($q);
        $xx->execute([]);
        $rows = $xx->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $n = count($rows);
        $q = "drop temporary table t1temp";
        $xx = $connect_pdo->prepare($q);
        $xx->execute([]);
        echo "<p>" . var_dump($rows);
   

// The output
 
        F:\xampp-htdocs\project_template\user\test.php:11:
array (size=0)
  empty
F:\xampp-htdocs\project_template\user\test.php:24:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'id' => null
      public 'i0' => null
      public 'i1' => null
      public 't1' => null
      public 'c1' => null
      public 'e1' => null
      public 'u1' => null
      public 's1' => null
      public 'x1' => null
      public 'rt' => null
      public 'i2' => null
  public 'count(*)' => string '0' (length=1)
```

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer, unfortunately in my case it wouldn't work, since I never know the structure of the query that the front-end will send,  especially with complex queries.

Comment: In my answer I added an other way to see the column names wne no result set.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helped me a bunch :D

Comment: Interesting option to create a temporary table for every query! Anyone, how do you assess the performance of this approach?

Comment: As for the trick of adding "count(*) as ignore" to the query, I guess that would automatically group the result set; which means you must then go back and provide a "GROUP BY" clause. Right?

Answer (score -1):

Check out [PDOStatement::getColumnMeta](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)